# How to make dynamic tabs using jquery

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have this code for now aiming to create tabs:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#custom-tab-0-8cf04a9734132302f96da8e113e80ce5" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#custom-tab-0-cce99c598cfdb9773ab041d54c3d973a" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="custom-tab-0-8cf04a9734132302f96da8e113e80ce5" class="tab-pane active" tabindex="-1">
            Content goes here<br>
        </div>
        <div id="custom-tab-0-cce99c598cfdb9773ab041d54c3d973a" class="tab-pane" tabindex="-1">
            Nothing comes here<br>
        </div>
    </div>

CSS:

ul.nav.nav-tabs {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    margin-top: 2%;
}

ul.nav.nav-tabs li {
    float: left;
}
ul.nav.nav-tabs a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}
li.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

How can I create multiple tabs with jQuery, display the content of the the TAB that I click only and add a class active to it?

Note: I cannot change much on the html structure because it is a WordPress site and I used short-code to generate the tabs. I simply styled and tried the jQuery.

For now I can see all the content of  all tabs at once.But what I want is only one tab active and the others closed.
When I click on a next tab,it should display the content of that tab online,have the class active and deactivate the class active that the previous active tab had.

I started using this code just to test functionality when I click on each TAB but I don't think it is a good practice to use child selectors cause I might have more than 2 tabs:

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
    $("ul.nav.nav-tabs li:first-child a").click(function(){
        alert("You clicked on the first-child");
    });
    $("ul.nav.nav-tabs li:nth-child(2) a").click(function(){
        alert("You clicked on the second child");
    });            
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Visiblary:

```
/*
 * params:
 *     - selector: jQuery selector
 *     - init: function which gets the Visiblary object to initialize it
 *     - events: object/array
 *         - root: a selector which contain all the affected tags, default is "body"
 *         - types: array, which contains the string representation of the events
 *         - selector: inner selector to identify the target set
 *         - handler: handler function
 */
function Visiblary(params) {
    var instance = this;
    if (!params.toggleClass) {
        params.toggleClass = "invisible";
    }
    this.hideAll = function() {
        $(params.selector).addClass(params.toggleClass);
        return instance;
    };
    this.hideSubset = function(subsetSelector) {
        $(params.selector).filter(subsetSelector).addClass(params.toggleClass);
        return instance;
    };
    this.hideOnly = function(subsetSelector) {
        $(params.selector).not(subsetSelector).removeClass(params.toggleClass);
        $(params.selector).filter(subsetSelector).addClass(params.toggleClass);
        return instance;
    };
    this.showAll = function() {
        $(params.selector).removeClass(params.toggleClass);
        return instance;
    };
    this.showSubset = function(subsetSelector) {
        $(params.selector).filter(subsetSelector).removeClass(params.toggleClass);
        return instance;
    };
    this.showOnly = function(subsetSelector) {
        $(params.selector).not(subsetSelector).addClass(params.toggleClass);
        $(params.selector).filter(subsetSelector).removeClass(params.toggleClass);
        return instance;
    };
    this.invert = function() {
        $(params.selector).each(function() {
            $(this).hasClass(params.toggleClass) ? $(this).removeClass(params.toggleClass) : $(this).addClass(params.toggleClass);
        });
        return instance;
    };
    if (!!params.init) {
        params.init(this);
    }
    if (!!params.events) {
        for (var event in params.events) {
            $(!!params.events[event].root ? params.events[event].root : "body").on(params.events[event].types.join(" "), params.events[event].selector, params.events[event].handler);
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

With that you can achieve what you want and more. invisible is a CSS class:

```
.invisible {
    display: none;
}
```

EDIT:

This file should be a separate .js file inside a `script` tag positioned below the `script` which loads jQuery. It is recommended to initialize your `Visiblary` objects inside the load event of `$(function() {})`. Example:

```
$(function() {
    //New visiblary object, things will be callable using visiblary.
    var visiblary = Visiblary({
        //Elements corresponding to selector
        selector: "#chat-window > .chat-content",
        //In this example we have a single event, which is clicking on
        //a .chat-tab-set child of #chat-window. This will trigger showOnly
        //with the index corresponding data-index
        events: [
            {
                root: "#chat-window > .chat-tab-set",
                types: ["click"],
                selector: ".chat-tab",
                handler: function() {
                    visiblary.showOnly(":eq(" + $(this).data("index") + ")");
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: How exactly can I place this snippet in my jQuery file?
inside the ready function?  Please explain  If you don't mind cause ma failing to make it work on my side

Comment: @WosleyAlarico, you do not need to put it into the jQuery file. How is it not working for you? Do you get an error? What did you expect, what did you try and how did you fail?

Comment: Here my snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/o993u9su/2/
If you check from the snippet, only the content of the active tab is mean to be active.

Comment: @WosleyAlarico, you forgot to add jQuery to your snippet and you did not really use Visiblary. I strongly suggest that you should use a few tutorials, because without those life will be very difficult. However, your problem is solved here: https://jsfiddle.net/o993u9su/3/

Comment: .Thanks for the help. I ended up having to use a plugin but your help was useful regardless and yes I need a more tutorials on jquery still. At the moment I only know basic jquery concepts that I allow me to play a bit with the DOM..But basic.
I know there are lots of tutorials on the web but will also be glad if you can refer some good ones.
Regards

Comment: @WosleyAlarico, I have given you a working Fiddle. Is there a reason you have chosen not to go with it?

Comment: @ Lajos Arpad. Yes there is. Problem is that I am developing the site with WordPress and the page has about 6 Tabs each with their own information that will be frequently updated,therefore I cant really hard code so I had to use a Plugin and just style such.

Comment: @WosleyAlarico, can you share more details about your filter? That is needed to determine whether the problem is solvable. No need to give me the real details, you can describe a technically equivalent case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`index(element)`](https://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element) method to get the index of element which is clicked in collection on matched elements. Note it return zero based position.

> Search for a given element from among the matched elements.

```
//Hide inactive tab content
$('.tab-content :not(.active)').hide();

//Cache elements 
var navigationAnchorElements = $("ul.nav.nav-tabs li a");

//bind click handler
navigationAnchorElements.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //remove active class and hide content pane
    $('.tab-content .active').removeClass('active').hide();

    //Show current active content pane and add Class
    $(this.getAttribute("href")).addClass('active').show();

    //remove active class from parent elemets
    $("ul.nav.nav-tabs li.active").removeClass('active');

    //add active class to current element
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');

    var index = navigationAnchorElements.index(this) + 1;
    alert("You clicked on the " + index + " child" );
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var navigationAnchorElements = $("ul.nav.nav-tabs li a");
  $('.tab-content :not(.active)').hide();
  navigationAnchorElements.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.tab-content .active').removeClass('active').hide();
    $(this.getAttribute("href")).addClass('active').show();

    $("ul.nav.nav-tabs li.active").removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');

    var index = navigationAnchorElements.index(this) + 1;
    //  alert("You clicked on the " + index + " child" + this.dataset.id);
  });
});
```

```css
ul.nav.nav-tabs {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
ul.nav.nav-tabs li {
  float: left;
}
ul.nav.nav-tabs a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}
li.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#custom-tab-0-8cf04a9734132302f96da8e113e80ce5" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#custom-tab-0-cce99c598cfdb9773ab041d54c3d973a" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="custom-tab-0-8cf04a9734132302f96da8e113e80ce5" class="tab-pane active" tabindex="-1">
    Content goes here
    <br>
  </div>
  <div id="custom-tab-0-cce99c598cfdb9773ab041d54c3d973a" class="tab-pane" tabindex="-1">
    Nothing comes here
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I display the content of the tab that I click only and add the class active to it?
Thanks in advanced

Comment: @WosleyAlarico https://jsfiddle.net/ff6jsf9h/ note I have use `data-href` instead of `href` for anchor tabs in you application you should use `href` so you can replace `$(this.dataset.href)` with `$(this.href)`

Comment: I tested from your jsfiddle and it works. But  when I replace $(this.dataset.href) with $(this.href). The expected does not happen when I click on a tab. Of course I also replaced the html snippet with the one I have.
please check my snippet:https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/o993u9su/1/

Comment: @WosleyAlarico, use `this.getAttribute("href")` instead of `this.href` updated code snippet https://jsfiddle.net/7ck0uLsy/